# Create custom log level in Spring boot logback-spring.xml

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback, loggerfactory

Team,

I want to be create custom log level in logback-spring.xml in spring boot. like we have info, debug,warn same like want to create my own custom level.

any suggestion ?